# what is the best way to render data on asp.net on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

our project is developed with dot net 3.5 and we use update panel ajax:toolkit and WebFormControls.
now we want to upgrade the project and use ajax jquery Instead update panels and the ajax:toolkit. 
my Question is: what is the best way to do it?
should i need to get the data on server convert it to json and render it on client(without the use WebFormControls.
or on page load i have to use Web Form Controls and when user do change render it on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods sounds like a good fit, because you can call the `static` page methods from jQuery's `.ajax()` function and the ASP.NET AJAX page methods automatically encode to JSON.

Here is an example that will display the server's time upon loading of the page (DOM ready) into a DIV named `Results`:

Markup:

```
<div id="Results"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPage.aspx/GetDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            // Take the JSON returned from the page method and put it into the DIV
            $("#Results").text(result.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Note: ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods must be `static`, as they do not have access to the actual page or any controls on the page. They are great for making async calls from the client to retrieve data from the server and have it automatically returned as JSON, which the client can then display, parse, etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer,  when user change something on the page, i understand that the best Solution is ajax jquery, but on page load on the first time shold i use WebFormControls and render the data on server or to use Only html control and to render the data on client?

Comment: @matishw - unfortunately, there is no best answer, depends upon the situation, what kind of data are you rendering? Tables of data (I would lean towards using WebForms controls for this and then use jQuery to react to events on the grid and retrieve or save data)? Data-entry labels and text boxes (I would lean towards using HTML controls and jQuery to react to events)? The good news is that WebForms controls and jQuery can co-exist rather peacefully. :-)